# LINQ Query Sub-Objects C sharp 8 and asp.net core 3.0

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a LINQ query which acts on a database object as below

```
Ticket:
MyTask (list)

MyTask:
Id (int)
Cats (List of Cats)
Status (string)

Cat:
Assignee (string)

             context.Ticket
            .Where(x => x.Type == "Animal")

            .Include(x => x.MyTasks)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.Cats);

            .Where(x => x.Status != "Collected")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.MyTask.Where(y => y.Assignee == User.Identity.Name)) //Doesn't work
            .SelectMany(x => x.MyTask.Select(y => new MyModel(y, x.Id)))
            .ToList();
```

This problem is that I can't directly access y.Assignee == User.Identity.Name.

```
Cannot convert expression type IEnumerable.<MyProject.Models.MyTask> to return type bool.
```

I want to end up with an list of objects created from the Cat and the task Id based on a user assigned to a cat (ie new MyModel(cat, taskId)).

This is C sharp 8 and asp.net core 3.0.

So each ticket of type animal might have tasks -> which might have a cat object -> which might include an assignee.

Comment: " it gives me an error saying it cannot resolve bool." can we have the exact error message please

Comment: Sorry, my IDE isn't letting me copy errors and I assumed my LINQ was just nonsense - updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
    .SelectMany(x => x.MyTask.Where(y => y.Assignee == User.Identity.Name).Select(y => new MyModel(y, x.Id)))
```